# How to change material ui select menu's drop down colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just want to change the color of the drop down menu's background color but nothing I'm trying is working and I am left baffled.

There isn't much more I can say, stackoverflow wants me to add more text but all I can say is I've been googling various solutions and nothing has worked so far.

```
const BootstrapInput = withStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            'label + &': {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
            },
        },
        selectMenu: {
            color: 'rgba(1,1,255,1)',
            backgroundColor: "#rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            "& ul": {
                backgroundColor: "#rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            },
            "& li": {
                backgroundColor: "#rgba(255,0,0,1)",
                fontSize: 12,
            },
        },
        input: {
            borderRadius: 0,
            position: 'inherit',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
            border: '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
            fontSize: 15,
            padding: '10px 26px 10px 12px',
            transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
            // Use the system font instead of the default Roboto font.
            fontFamily: [
                '-apple-system',
                'BlinkMacSystemFont',
                '"Segoe UI"',
                'Roboto',
                '"Helvetica Neue"',
                'Arial',
                'sans-serif',
                '"Apple Color Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
            ].join(','),
            '&:focus': {
                borderRadius: 4,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,190,255,0.6)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            },
        },
    }),
)(InputBase);

<Select
                            native
                            value={currentClass}
                            onChange={updateClassChosenFunction}
                            input={<BootstrapInput />}
                        >
                            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                            <option value={1}>One</option>
                            <option value={2}>Twu</option>
                            <option value={3}>Three</option>
                            
                        </Select>
```

Comment: The `InputBase` API has not `selectMenu` rule name. I think adding a background color to `root` should work. Also note that `"#rgba(255,0,0,1)"` is not valid syntax.

Comment: You can also try inspecting that element and see which CSS styles are applied, if it is not working this way, you can [import a stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things that we should do to apply the desired style.
First for the style of the input, and the second one for the style of the paper dropdown(if we want to change its style too).
So, We can create appropriate style by makeStyles as below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  //other part of the code//
  paper: {
    background: "red",
    color: "white"
  },
  input: {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
    "&:focus": {
      borderRadius: 4,
      borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)",
      boxShadow: "0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,190,255,0.6)",
      background: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
    }
  }
}));
```

Then we need to apply them to the `Select` component. [According to the doc](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props), `MenuProps` and `inputProps` are responsible for these changes:

```
    <Select
      MenuProps={{
        classes: {
          paper: classes.paper
        }
      }}
      inputProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.input
        }
      }}
     // other attributes//
    >
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0sq18?file=/demo.js:1181-1549)